# Forign key violation while creating a parent/child relation in postgresql when transaction is split between two connections

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, transactions, foreign-keys

My application is creating a record in table risk_factors and a record in table investigation under the same hibernate transaction. Each table is under a different schema and there is FK relation between these tables.

The application’s data sources are configured as below where each schema has its own data source. Each insertion is executed under different user as shown in the logs below.

**Datasource Sample**

```
<dataSource id="notifDs" jndiName="jdbc/notifDs" type="javax.sql.XADataSource" connectionSharing="MatchCurrentState" transactional="true" ><properties.postgresql currentSchema="anotif" databaseName="test1" password="233274" portNumber="5444" serverName="localhost" user="aconsent"/><jdbcDriver  javax.sql.XADataSource="com.edb.xa.PGXADataSource"><library><fileset dir="${ThirdPartyLibsDir}/lib/edb" includes="*.jar"/></library></jdbcDriver></dataSource>
```

Checking EDB, we observe that it is creating connection(s) per user
[connecions to DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBNRz.png)
**Error**

The transaction fails with the following error
Caused by: com.edb.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "risk_factors" violates foreign key constraint "fk_inv"
Detail: Key (investigation_id)=(1465) is not present in table "investigation".

**Logs excerpt from the insertions and the error**

```
2022-11-16 01:09:41.639 AST acase test1 38968 180488 10/555 63746e59.9838 LOG:  00000: execute S_31: insert into INVESTIGATION (CREATED_BY, CREATED_ON, IS_DELETED_IND, lock_seq_num,…
```

```
2022-11-16 01:09:45.041 AST apanoram test1 44492 180541 22/790 63746ec8.adcc ERROR:  23503: insert or update on table "risk_factors" violates foreign key constraint "fk_inv"
```

Where the log format is: %t %u %d %p %x %v %c

- %u = user name
- %d = database name
- %p = process ID
- %m = timestamp with milliseconds
- %c = session ID
- %v = virtual transaction ID
- %x = transaction ID (0 if none)

**Note**

- This case is working fine in oracle.
- No issue when the two statements are running under the same user [needs code change in application]
- FK causing issue has the deferral flag turned on, same as the statement_deferral defined in the server config

I suspect that a transaction can't read its own writes as the two statements are running under different processes.

Comment: If the two statements are running in different processes, then in what sense are they part of the same transaction?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, JDBC transactions are tied to (JDBC) connections.  JavaEE has a distributed transaction system that can federate distinct DB transactions, but that's probably not enough for your needs.  I think your best bet is to add code to ensure that any needed changes to table `investigations` are committed before the dependent changes to `risk_factors`.  You may be able to soften the requirements by working with the DB transaction isolation level and / or making enformcement of the FK constraints involved initially deferred.

Comment: They are running within the same hibernate transaction, but it seems the application is creating a connection per datasource and sending its insert statement through that connection.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am using XAdatasource for both cases oracle and edb and yes it works for oracle.

Comment: Given that each schema has its own datasource, it is not in the least surprising that Hibernate uses a separate connection for objects from one schema than it does for objects from the other.  But I would also expect that to follow from each of the "different processes" and "different users" characteristics you describe.

Comment: Using an XAdatasource has little to do with any of this, except that such datasources provide connections that can participate in distributed transactions.  But again, I would not expect that to be enough.  That it happens to work with Oracle does not imply that it ought to work with any other database, nor even to keep working with Oracle as the application changes.  Nor necessarily to be reliable with Oracle.

Comment: @ 
John Bollinger 
yes..I also doubt that XAdatasource is related, but I wanted to give full context and reply to the question about the distributed Tx. I agree with your solutions such as relaxing the fk constraint and assuring that parent key is committed first. These solutions have their business downside though, so I want to leave them as a last resort. My concern now is understand why I am experiencing this and is this related to the different processes?

Comment: The SQL error already tells you that you are experiencing the issue because the updates to table `investigations` are not seen by the updates to table `risk_factors`.  Supposing that the relationship is mapped, I would expect Hibernate to avoid such issues when using the same connection for all entities.  But to the best of my knowledge it cannot provide the same DB connection to two different processes at the same time.  Nor do I expect it to use the same connection even in the same process for entities associated with different datasources.

Comment: Nor do I expect Hibernate in general to be able to coordinate entity modifications by separate processes, unless possibly if access to the persistence unit were gated by a single component instance shared by all cooperating processes (a session bean, for example), with JTA transactions in play.